# How to run .exe file when linux system starts up?

Tags: linux, c

i have generated .exe file from C file (ie filename.c ) after compiling in linux machine with -O option. I wish to know about how to run that .exe file when linux system starts up ?

Comment: Which Linux distro are you using?

Comment: What do you mean .exe file? Did you compile this for Windows? Can you compile it for Linux?

Comment: Which Linux distro are you using?
Please elaborate what all things you tried, what did not work, etc.?
You will get better answers and in less time :)

Comment: exe file and linux in one sentence still is somehow a wtf-moment :D

Answer (score 4):

Compile filename.c  under linux and just add the command to /etc/rc.d/rc.local. This would get executed  when computer boots. Another way would be to create a script for it in /etc/rc.d/init.d/ and then make links to it in the relevant run levels /etc/rc.d/rc3.d/, /etc/rc.d/rc5.d/

Comment: I'd suggest rc.local for the initial try - its simpler especially in light of new dependency based init.d systems, such as upstart.

Answer (score 1):

To run exe files on Linux you need Wine.

So first you have to start wine, and then your exe.
I guess you have to put these into /etc/rc.d/(Choose appropriate run level)

Comment: Yes, i tried this, but didnt work.

Comment: If you have access to the source code (i.e. filename.c), you should rebuild the program on Linux rather then using Wine.

Answer (score 1):

> Hi, i have generated .exe file from C file (ie filename.c ) after compiling in linux machine with -O option

I am assuming you are using GCC and you mean '-o' instead of '-O'. In this case you have named the file to be "file.exe", although on Linux you don't need to specify the file extension as "exe".

So you have done something like

`gcc filename.c -o file.exe`

You can then run the program using

`./file.exe`

If you would like to have the compiled application run at startup, you will need to put the compiled file in a common location and investigate which startup scripts run for your distribution (`init.rc`). You may find [this](http://embraceubuntu.com/2005/09/07/adding-a-startup-script-to-be-run-at-bootup/) helpful.

Once you have found how to add a startup script then you can add `/var/myapp/test.exe` to an existing startup script or write your own.